Why am I unable to launch Virtual Box via Vagrant on macOS?
I'm going to use Vagrant for the first time. I am using an M1 Mac.
My vagrant up command is failing with below message:
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'app' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'mysql1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'mysql2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'mysql3' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'mysql4' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'mysql5' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> app: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> app: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> app: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    app: Adapter 1: nat
    app: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> app: Forwarding ports...
    app: 3000 (guest) => 2000 (host) (adapter 1)
    app: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> app: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> app: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "37d985a0-dc89-4d49-a7f9-02af2ca9b5a4", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The VM session was aborted
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession

I'm using it on macOS. I have also installed Virtual Box.
As part of troubleshooting purpose, I have tried reinstalling vagrant hostmanager, however there also I'm getting below message:
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager

Installing the 'vagrant-hostmanager' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Vagrant failed to properly resolve required dependencies. These
errors can commonly be caused by misconfigured plugin installations
or transient network issues. The reported error is:

conflicting dependencies logger (= 1.6.0) and logger (= 1.6.1)
  Activated logger-1.6.1
  which does not match conflicting dependency (= 1.6.0)

  Conflicting dependency chains:
    logger (= 1.6.1), 1.6.1 activated

  versus:
    logger (= 1.6.0)

  Gems matching logger (= 1.6.0):
    logger-1.6.0


try looking in the virtual box logs, I don't think this is a vagrant issue at all

If you are on ARM it sounds like you might have some success with the latest developer builds https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=537634#p537634

You are trying to run Vagrant on an Apple Silicon Mac: An M1.
Because while Vagrant might technically work in Apple Silicon, the underlying issue is Virtual Box currently only supports Intel Macs. Vagrant is just a bunch of scripts to automate VM creation; Vagrant will technically “work” but Virtual Box itself won’t work.
Attempting to run VirtualBox on Apple Silicon will only result in failure.
